# Node.js: TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have a weird error:

```
var http = require("http");
var request = require("request");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
        }
    });
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

The idea is for it to listen as a webserver, and then do a request.
But this is what I get as error:

```
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/oplgkim/Desktop/iformtest/j.js:8:2)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2056:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:120:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1946:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I installed request, so that's not it :)

Comment: Access to the `request` global variable is lost as you have a local variable with the same name.

Comment: That hit the spot, why dont you post that as an answer so i can give you points...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Access to the `request` global variable is lost as you have a local variable with the same name.  Renaming either one of the variables will solve this issue:

```
var http = require("http"); var request = require("request");

http.createServer(function(req, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
      }
    })
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are no longer able to access the global variable 'request'. You need to rename your local variable 'request' with some other name and the problem will be resolved.